# Need to run the app in android device after killing it in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, background-fetch

Need to run the app in an android device after killing it in a flutter. I'm using background_fetch, it works fine when app is live. but it won't run after killing the app.

```
 BackgroundFetch.configure(BackgroundFetchConfig(
  minimumFetchInterval: 15,
  forceAlarmManager: false,
  stopOnTerminate: false,
  startOnBoot: true,
  enableHeadless: true,
  requiresBatteryNotLow: false,
  requiresCharging: false,
  requiresStorageNotLow: false,
  requiresDeviceIdle: false,
  requiredNetworkType: NetworkType.NONE,
), _onBackgroundFetch).then((int status) {
  print('[BackgroundFetch] configure success: $status');
  setState(() {
    _status = status;
  });

}).catchError((e) {
  print('[BackgroundFetch] configure ERROR: $e');
  setState(() {
    _status = e;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WorkManager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) plugin to do so.

```
const myTask = "syncWithTheBackEnd";

void main() {
  Workmanager.initialize(callbackDispatcher);
  Workmanager.registerOneOffTask(
    "1",
    myTask, //This is the value that will be returned in the callbackDispatcher
    initialDelay: Duration(minutes: 5),
    constraints: WorkManagerConstraintConfig(
      requiresCharging: true,
      networkType: NetworkType.connected,
    ),
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}

void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager.executeTask((task) {
    switch (task) {
      case myTask:
        print("this method was called from native!");
        break;
      case Workmanager.iOSBackgroundTask:
        print("iOS background fetch delegate ran");
        break;
    }

    //Return true when the task executed successfully or not
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}
```

The complete article [medium article](https://medium.com/vrt-digital-studio/flutter-workmanager-81e0cfbd6f6e)

Answer (score 0):

Try using isolate it will give what you want , here is the link https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_isolate

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).